# Convert Cdata to Java String

Tags: java, android, xml

I am recieving data from an xOS .plist file. 
In the XML file there is a data element with text like:
DATA ELEMENT(15366): AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAE53NlYW4AAAABAAAAFQAAAAAAAAG2dmlkZQAAAAEAAAAQAAAAAAAAACJzcHRsAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAYXZjMQAAAAAAGAAAAwAAAAAgdHBybAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAwAAHgAAAAAAGAAAACRkcmF0AAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAH0AAAAAAAAAAMAAAADAAAAABVtcHNvAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABhtZnJhAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABhwc

How can I convert this data to a normal String in Java/Android

Comment: Are you told that it represents a normal string? It looks like base64. If it had been a normal string then the normal string would be there.

Comment: It is a plist with properties of a movie file and I think the data represents tags of the movie file. All the other elements are normal Strings, but this element has the "data" type when I open the plist on my mac.

Comment: Did you already a Base64.decode() to see what byte[]s you get?

Comment: What is a plist? How does that 'look'?